# How to update multiple items in list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list and a dictionary.

Dictionary's key and value are items of the list.

I want to loop through dictionary and if list.id and key match change item with value.

I did this and dont know if its right or wrong but worked for me:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dict)
{
    list.Where(x => x.Id== entry.Key)
        .Select(y => { y.item= entry.Value; return y; })
        .ToList();
}
```

Now also I need to change date with datetime.now. Can I do it in the same linq if I can how?

Comment: This is a pretty bad way of doing whatever you're doing. Please show us some more code so that we can advise you of the correct way to do this.

Comment: LINQ is for querying things, not changing things. Do not write LINQ queries that cause changes as a side effect; use a loop. Clarify whether you’re trying to update the list data into the dictionary or the dictionary data into the list - it looks from the code like the data from the dictionary is used to update the list?

Comment: (in which case this is perhaps the worst way you could do this; not only does it have side effects, but it makes dictionary fast lookup pointless and does a loop-of-loops - your dictionary might as well be a plain list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, we should avoid Select for updating items in the list. For update, we have other LINQ extensions such as ForEach. Moreover, you can simplify the iterations.

```
    list.Where(listItem => dict.Keys.Contains(listItem.Id))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(listItem =>
        {
            listItem.item  = dict[item.Id].Value; 
        });
```

Comment: thanks. I am new to linq and select was the first thing came to my mind. I also searched a a solution and came up to list.foreach but couldnt worked with condition

Comment: @eomer Be aware that `list.Where(condition).ToList()` will loop through the entire contents of `list` to test if each item matches the condition. It will then build an entirely new list object (`.ToList()`) with the matching items, before then looping through this new list. So if `list` contains 100 items, and `dict` contains 50 matching entries, you will loop through a total of 150 items.

Comment: Yes, might be there is negligible performance impact but that totally depends on data size. Might be OP's data is not that huge. Anyway, I liked your solution too. Basically, it's the difference between functional and imperative programming styles. I prefer LINQ for better readability and OP's question also included linq tag.

Comment: @A.T. I'm not complaining about your answer. You already got my upvote, but I wanted to make sure that eomer understands that `.Where(...).ToList()` isn't magic (i.e. it _does_ have a cost). I got the impression from the comment on my answer that eomer doesn't fully appreciate how LINQ works.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's see what your current code does:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dict) // loop through each key/value pair in the dictionary
{
    list.Where(x => x.Id== entry.Key).Select(y => { y.item= entry.Value; return y; }) // construct a query on `list` and project the result using Select
    .ToList(); // Force evaluation of the query in order to execute the projection
}
```

The projection code actually modifies the source item (`y.item = ~~`), which is why this "works", but it's definitely not the right way to do it.

Unless you have a huge list (in which case the list should probably be changed), you're doing this in the least efficient way possible. Dictionaries are designed for close to O(1) lookups, and you're throwing this away with the way that you're using it. You should instead iterate through the list:

```
foreach (var listItem in list)
```

And then see if there is a corresponding item in the dictionary:

```
if (dict.TryGetValue(listItem.Key, out var value))
```

From here, we can update the list item with the new value. Putting it all together:

```
foreach (var listItem in list)
{
    if (dict.TryGetValue(listItem.Key, out var value))
    {
        listItem.item = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what if the list contains 1kk items and dictionary only 100? (:

Comment: But, in your code, you are traversing the list 100 times.  Invert it (as shown above) and you only traverse the list once.

Comment: @ekvalizer As I said: _"Unless you have a huge list (in which case the list should probably be changed) ..."_ Even so, this method will be more efficient than iterating the 1000-item list 100 times.

Comment: @ekvalizer if your list contains 100 items and your dictionary contains 1000 your loops approach (LINQ uses loops internally) might loop 100,000 times! If by kk you mean million then the problem just gets worse. If you have a million items in a list and you have 100 updates in a dictionary then you have your data storage containers the wrong way round. The million items should be in the dictionary and then it’s 100 fast lookups rather than banging a million items to see if they’re in the update list

Comment: makes sense but in my case list is always larger than dictionary. gonna work with other solutions. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have some aversion to using for loops you could use List.ForEach, which is a list thing not a LINQ thing:

```
list.ForEach(x => {
  if(dictionary.TryGetValue(x.Id, out var s)) {
    x.Item = s;
    x.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
  }
});
```

But how about making the property setter for Item maintain the modified date then you don’t have to remember to set it everywhere you make a change to Item? (Though that is not an excuse for carrying on with the LINQ side effect route in the question)